# From where to download os 6 simulator in xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new in iphone development .I downloaded xcode 5 in which os 7 simulator inbuild come.But I need os 5 and os 6 simulator from where I will download ?

Comment: Should be in Preferences/Downloads/Components.

Comment: After you download the iOS 6 simulator, you should make sure (if you haven't already) that your project's "deployment target" is 6.0 (or whatever is appropriate). For new projects, the default deployment target is iOS 7.0, in which case you won't see the option of running on the earlier versions of the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Xcode->preferences, then Downloads tab and it should be under components.

Comment: There is a two column one is documentation and component.I need only 6.1 simulator .but when I check and install it install all thing

Comment: There should be a down arrow on the RHS of the line containing iOS 6.1 simulator if you click that it should only download 6.1 and nothing else.

Comment: progress bar is not increasing and decreasing so I am not able to find is it downloading or not

Comment: Not sure could be servers are under heavy load or your internet is running slowly. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Choose XCode top menu, select Preferences, choose Downloads and here you should be able to see list of components to install.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Set the active scheme" in the upper-left corner, and click [More Simulators...] item; Downloads dialog will open. Under the "Components" group, choose the simulator that you would like to install, and double-click the down arrow.